# PHP — Testing Array Value

Tags: arrays, wordpress, checkbox, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using checkboxes in Advanced Custom Fields for WordPress. I only have one value set for it, that being a value of 'Yes'

And so I have setup the following test:

```
<?php if (!in_array('Yes', get_field('banner'))) : ?>
```

However, for those posts that *don't* have a value specified, I get the following error:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in
>   /var/sites/d/dev-chwng.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/chwng/loop-slideshow.php
>   on line 19

I imagine because for the items where 'Yes' isn't selected, that in turn means there is no array called 'banner' that has been set

I tried putting the whole thing inside a statement of `<?php if (get_field('banner')) : ?>` which prevents the error, but it stops the script working from how I need it (hard to explain).

Does anyone know how I can determine a value of 'Yes' without throwing an error?

Comment: @rnevius sorry I didn't get a notification email for some reason, I shall check shortly and get back to you! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could additionally (first) verify that it's an array, using [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php):

```
<?php 
    $banner = get_field('banner');
    if ( is_array($banner) && !in_array('Yes', $banner) ) : ?>
```

This will make the script move on to the `else` statement immediately, if `get_field()` doesn't return an array.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work unfortunately. It prevents the error, but due to how the WP plugin works it stops the loop working how I need... thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

Due to how the WP plugin works, it seems the only way I could get it working how I need it was with

`<?php if ( get_field('banner') == '' ) : ?>`